# How to set the default language for all users or browsers

Tags: django, django-i18n

There are two working versions of the translation on the site - Russian and English using `i18n`. How to make sure that everyone has a website loaded in Russian and then, at the request of the user, he can change it to English?

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    ...
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', _('Russian')),
    ('en', _('English')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Kiev'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: @dirkgroten all works but I want not to use django auto detecting language and want to use one language for all users for default

Comment: If you're not using i18n_patterns, then the first thing used is the cookie, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference). So if you set the cookie it will ignore the browser's Accept-Language header. Now for the first request, which doesn't have the cookie, I would add my own middleware (before LocaleMiddleware) to add the cookie to the request if it's not set. When the user changes the language, you just change the cookie.